# EC2 instance refusing access to MongoDB Tools

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

Recently after changing the security parameters of my MongoDB on my EC2 instance as well as my EC2 security group, I have no longer been able to use mongodump, mongoexport, etc from my local machine. My MongoDB instance is running and I am able to connect to the Mongo shell from creating an SSH tunnel on my local machine.

Currently, the security group for my EC2 instance allows access to port 27017 from only the server itself and my IP. In my mongodb.conf file I have the settings as:

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
port = 27017
```

I have seen other solutions that include commenting these settings out or changing the security group rules of the EC2 instance, but I would prefer to keep the security as strict as possible.

So, my question is, is there a way that I am able to perform mongodump etc on the server from my local machine without changing the current security parameters since the connection is refused. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should be able to dump through the SSH tunnel also.

Comment: Beautiful, it works, thank you!